# Flutter with python backend

Tags: python, api, flutter, nlp, backend

i have a website python-based that consists of a form that i want to fill from flutter.
this form takes one input text field (get request )
when submit is pressed, it will generate an output based on the python script ( it is an natural language processing)
is it possible to connect to this website using flutter and fill the form ?
i have tried using 'HTTP' package in flutter but i was not able to connect to the form
any help will be appreciated
i tried the following:

```
    Future<String> sendQuery(query) async{
  final http.Response response = await http.get(
  'http://127.0.0.1:5000/getQuery/',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  use  this plugin navigate  to web site https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
 _launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
await launch(url);
 } else {
 throw 'Could not launch $url';
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help i really appreciate. Is there a way to get to fill the form, press submit and get the output on a widget in flutter ? here is my specific question. i have been surfing the internet so far but i cannot get good questions

Comment: yeah you can do this

Comment: I am checking the Flutter package 'http' , to send and get requests , so if i want to send the sentence to the form on the website, how can i write it ? i was thinking about the code i have written in the code . but how can i press the submit on the website form to get the needed output ?  do you have any idea ?

Comment: There are two way what you want
  1. You want to  fill  form from flutter and send request then get response  back show in flutter   widget.

2.  If you want go website fill form there and get response in flutter widget.